# Iterate over list while appending to another list

Tags: swi-prolog

I'm new to Prolog. The following predicate is supposed to handle a list of strings each containing a first and last name separated by a space. It's meant to pass through each element, separate it by space into an element for FirstName and another for LastName, and add these values to a list of FirstNames and a list of LastNames. In the end, it should return a list of all FirstNames and LastNames both corresponding to the order of the original list. I'm struggling to get this to work.

```
populate([]).
populate([H|T], FirstNames, LastNames) :-
    split_string(H, " ", " ", Elems),
    Elems = [FirstName, LastName],
    append(FirstNames, [FirstName], FirstNames2),
    append(LastNames, [LastName], LastNames2),
    populate(T, FirstNames, LastNames).
```

For example, if given

```
?- populate(["Peter Parker", "Bruce Wayne"], FirstNames, LastNames),
```

it should return

```
FirstNames = ["Peter", "Bruce"]
```

and

```
LastNames = ["Parker", "Wayne"].
```

Comment: Some sample query with expected result?

Comment: I edited the post with one.

Answer (score 1):

Coding the problem in SWI-Prolog, with the following pecularities:

- Use Definite Clause Grammars to separate a *Name* into *First Name* and *Last Name*
- Make use of library `dcg/basics`, more exactly of the rules [`nonblanks//1`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nonblanks//1) and [`blank//0`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=blank//0) to hndle non-whitespace and single-character-whitespace, respectively
- SWI-Prolog DCGs processing text assume a list-of-unicode-codes as input (as opposed to a list of characters), so we honor that by using [`atom_codes/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_codes/2) to split and recompose text-
- Make use of atoms throughout (`'John Wayne'`) instead of SWI-Prolog strings (`"John Wayne"`) for uniformity.
- Use [plunit](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) unit tests for illustration.

And so:

First write a litte predicate that seaprates a "name atom" into a "first name atom" and a "last name atom", using DCGs:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

name(First,Last) --> 
   nonblanks(FirstCodes),   % collect a list of codes for the first name 
   blank,                   % then comes a blank
   nonblanks(LastCodes),    % collect a list of codes for the last name
   { atom_codes(First,FirstCodes),   % fuse the codes into a "first name atom"
     atom_codes(Last,LastCodes) }.   % fuse the codes into a "last name atom"
     
separate(Name,First,Last) :-
   atom_codes(Name,NameCodes),
   phrase(name(First,Last),NameCodes).
```

`separate/3` and we can test that:

```
:- begin_tests(separate).

test(1) :-
   separate('Bruce Wayne',First,Last),
   assertion(First == 'Bruce'),
   assertion(Last == 'Wayne').

:- end_tests(separate).
```

Running the test cases looks good:

```
?- run_tests(separate).
% PL-Unit: separate . done
% test passed
true.
```

Now we just need to apply `separate/3` on a list of names. We could use `maplist/3` but let's just use a recursive definition:

```
% separate_all(+ListOfNames,-ListOfFirsts,.ListOfLasts)

separate_all([],[],[]).
separate_all([Name|Ns],[First|Fs],[Last|Ls]) :-
   separate(Name,First,Last),
   separate_all(Ns,Fs,Ls).
```

And a test case:

```
:- begin_tests(separate_all).

test(all_1) :-
   separate_all(['Peter Parker', 'Bruce Wayne'],FirstNames,LastNames),
   assertion(FirstNames == ['Peter','Bruce']),
   assertion(LastNames == ['Parker','Wayne']).

:- end_tests(separate_all).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests(separate_all).
% PL-Unit: separate_all . done
% test passed
true.
```